# running production mode in a flask even if used .flaskenv with FLASK_ENV=development

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a problem with a flask. My debug mode is off even if I initialized the FLASK_ENV  =development if .flaskenv file. What could be a problem? And also I am getting the Warning in terminal "This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead."

I tried to explicitly put FLASK_ENV to development in .flaskenv file

Comment: Are you trying to run flask in production mode by setting `FLASK_ENV=development`?

Answer (score 0):

Since version [2.3.0](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-3-0) of Flask, the FLASK_ENV environment variable is no longer available.

To enable debug mode you can use the [--debug](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/cli/#debug-mode) argument of the CLI.

```bash
flask --app <filename> --debug run
# or 
flask --app <filename> run --debug
```

The note about the development server used appears as long as you do not use one of the options offered to [deploy your application](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/deploying/#deploying-to-production).

Comment: Thank you very much, I already resolved this issue with export command, but for future use of flask is it appropriate to use lower version flask? Or it is always better use the last one?

Comment: I would use the latest version as long as there are no problems with the update, which can be the case shortly after it is released. So a backup before the update is advisable.